# How to solve this error an jmetere

Tags: jmeter

```
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\Mm performance\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:116)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.getThreadService(ChromeDriverConfig.java:72)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:53)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:18)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:610)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:579)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:567)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/06/12 11:00:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting. No one wants to read through it all or format it for you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the latest version of ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html (if not yet)
2. Add the following line to *system.properties* file (the file lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   webdriver.chrome.driver=d:/chromedriver.exe
   ```

   You may have to substitute `d:/chromedriver.exe` with actual path to the ChromeDriver binary. Remember to use either forward slashes `c:/somefoler/someotherfolder` or escaped back slashes `c:\\somefolder\\someotherfolder` if you use Windows
3. Restart JMeter
4. ChromeDriver should work normally.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for advanced information on various JMeter properties and ways of setting, using and overriding them.