# Jmeter WebDriver don't start

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried to run WebDriver Sampler, but got problem with driver config.

First I tried to use Firefox Driver Config. When run only Firefox Driver Config (without any sampler) I see how Firefox launched but finally got error:
*org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows:  ddons.json found.*

Next I tried to use Chrome Driver config, but got error: 
*The driver executable does not exist.*

I tried to solve the problem like this: [How to solve this error an jmetere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795948/how-to-solve-this-error-an-jmetere?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but it doesn’t work.

[Image with config and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ssJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the tab with configuration path to driver

Picture with tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Firefox you need to ensure that you use **supported** Firefox version. The latest JMeter WebDriver Plugin [`kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:2.3`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/2.3) has transitive dependency on the [`selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.52.0) which means that you can use Firefox 45 or earlier with it.

Later Firefox versions will not work.

You can download Firefox 45 from [Mozilla FTP website](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0esr/)

More information: **Q. How do I Know Which Browsers are Supported?** chapter of [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide